# Conditional programming with file attributes (Batch files)

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, command-line-arguments

I am trying to build a simple batch file that will back up a document based on whether or not the archive flag has been set, however I am not sure how to check whether the archive flag has been set or not.  This is what I have so far, but I'm not sure of the attrib syntax (or if this is even the right command).  The error I get with this version is that it is not expecting the %1 variable (the file name) at this time.

```
@echo off

Rem **** Clears Screen ****
cls

Rem **** Ensure backup directory exists ****
if exist C:\backup\nul echo Backup directory located
if not exist C:\backup\nul echo Creating backup directory
if not exist C:\backup\nul mkdir C:\backup

Rem **** Checks if it has already been copied with archive flag ****
if attrib %1 equ +a goto nocopy
if attrib %1 equ -a goto copy

Rem **** Do not copy ****
:nocopy
echo File has already been backed up
pause

Rem **** Copies file ****
:copy
echo Copying %1
copy %1 C:\backup\%1
echo %1 backed up successfully!
pause
```

Comment: `xcopy` can handle the archive-attribute. See parameter `/a` or - even better - `/m`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `%1` as the reference to the file, you should pass it to batch file,

```
backupbatch.cmd miFileToCopy.txt
```

In the batch file, remember to check if you have a file name passed

```
if "%~1"=="" exit /b
```

Then to check for archive flag

```
set "fileAttribs=%~a1"
if "%fileAttribs:~2,1%"=="a" (
    echo flag is set 
) else (
    echo flag is not set
)
```

`%~a1` is the attribute list of the file referenced in %1. The third position in the list of attributes is the archive flag. Test it (first position in batch string is 0) for the `a` value to see if the flag is set.

Or `find` command can be used to test for the presence of the flag.

```
echo %~a1 | find "a" >nul && goto doCopy || goto noCopy
```